# Adding Multiple JLabels to ScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jscrollpane

I'm trying to get this code to stack each JLabel vertically with a new message (when add message is called). That way you can see every message by scrolling. I'm new to this so any thoughts? Right now, the code just replaces the textLabel with the new message.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;

public class ChatWindow {
static JFrame frame;
static JScrollPane jScrollPane;

public ChatWindow() {

    frame = new JFrame("Ring Chat");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JLabel label = new JLabel("Label");
    label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(label);


    JLabel textLabel = new JLabel("Welcome to Ring Chat!", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    textLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100));

    jScrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    jScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    jScrollPane.getViewport().add(textLabel);

    frame.add(jScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setSize(400, 800);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

public static void addMessage(String msg) {
    JLabel textLabel = new JLabel(msg, SwingConstants.CENTER);
    textLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
    jScrollPane.getViewport().add(textLabel, null);
    frame.add(jScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

public static void createWindow() {
    ChatWindow stuff = new ChatWindow();
}

public static void updateWindow() {
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add variable of `JPanel`

```
    static JScrollPane jScrollPane;
    static JPanel panel;
```

initialize it after `JLabel`

```
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setSize(500, 500);
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(20, 1));
        jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
        panel.add(label);
        JLabel textLabel = new JLabel("Welcome to Ring Chat!", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        textLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
        panel.add(textLabel);
```

and in `addMessage(String msg)` method add new `JLabel` to `JPanel` like this.

```
    public static void addMessage(String msg) {
        JLabel textLabel = new JLabel(msg, SwingConstants.CENTER);
        textLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
        panel.add(textLabel);
        frame.add(jScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
```

rest are same..

rather than adding `JLabel` use `JPanel` and at runtime add label on that `JPanel`. It will solve your problem..